# Link form objects to dynamic column locations

Tags: excel, vba

The basic description of what I am working with.

A user downloads an excel form with a range of data. The column headers can go as far out to column BD.

Despite the number of columns the user only needs to edit up to 12 of those columns.

The solution was to create a form, the user fills in the data and clicks a submit button, the form puts the data into the appropriate columns, and time lost from the user manually scrolling and clicking back and forth is regained.

A recent update, out of my control, has made the column heading location dynamic. So while the count and data entered remains the same the location is no longer fixed.

I am familiar with using find to locate the header and determine the column number by the active cell it finds it in. I am unfamiliar how to use that column number in place of the letter in my line of code that updates the current data.

I currently use:

```
Sheets("sheet name").Range("D" & Row).value = Me.txtDATA.Text
```

In this line 'Row' is a earlier determined value.

If column "D" moves to column "G" then using find will tell me that the location is column 7. I can then assign that number to a variable. What I don't know is how to use that variable to replace "D" in that line of code.

Comment: Probably easier to use Cells `Sheets("sheet name").Cells(row, col).value = Me.txtDATA.Text` where `row` and `col` are variables (in the case of D, col=4).

Comment: This worked. But I don't see the check mark to mark this answered.

Comment: there is not check mark to the comments